# How do i add more than two children in a TableRow in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Table with TableRows, i am trying to add more than two children in one of my table row to look like this :

[image]

But it's giving me error.

This is my code :

```
 TableRow(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Date to complete',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                  color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '05-03-22',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 10,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(50, 151, 219, 0.09),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'First time',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff34495E)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

This is what i tried :

```
 TableRow(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Date to complete',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                  color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  '05-03-22',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color:
                                          Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(50, 151, 219, 0.09),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'First time',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                          fontSize: 10,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          color: Color(0xff34495E)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

But this is the result :

[image]

The last container is always stretching to the right and not aligned to the desired UI i gave previously, even after using `mainAxisAlignment`.

Any solution to this would be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Expanded`, so the blue container takes only the minimum needed space. Then, to make the row take up all the available height and align vertically center, wrap it with `TableCell` with the `verticalAlignment:TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill`

```dart
TableRow(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Date to complete',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.8)),
      ),
    ),
    TableCell(
      verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              '05-03-22',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.8)),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(50, 151, 219, 0.09),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'First time',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Color(0xff34495E)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Perfect solution, very perfect, fit like a dress.. Thank you so much sir and i've learnt a lot from you today!!

Comment: Do you have a linkedin, i would love to connect with you