# How do i replicate this Ui in flutter for a bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to add more than one `bottomNavigationBar` in my scaffold of my appBar in flutter to look like this :

[image]

I have tried using `ListView` but it gives me error. However if i use just one of the material button widget, it works.

This is my code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final controller = Get.put(EServicesController());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 50,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Job Details".tr,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Color(0xff000000),
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leadingWidth: 15,
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
          onPressed: () => {Get.back()},
        ),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          // Get.find<LaravelApiClient>().forceRefresh();
          // await controller.refreshNotifications(showMessage: true);
          // Get.find<LaravelApiClient>().unForceRefresh();
        },
        child: JobDetailsHeader(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SendUpdateButton(),
    );
  }
```

I also tried using a column widget but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the UI layout shown in the picture, you can use a `Column`with two buttons inside it. The `MainAxisAlignment.end` property aligns the buttons to the bottom of the column. Also use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, so `Column` would not take all space.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('button 1')),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('button 1')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Sir this takes off all the content in the body of my `appBar`, i don't know why this happening so i will update my question with my full code. Please can you help?

Comment: Also use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to avoid crashes when vertical viewport has unbounded height.

Comment: @tesseract I edited answer to include `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` which should fix your problem

Comment: It worked! Thanks sir can you also help me with another question sir?

Comment: @tesseract If you have another problem, please post it as a new question. I will look at it and if I can help, I will answer it.

Comment: Okay sir, this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580561/how-do-i-add-more-than-two-children-in-a-tablerow-in-flutter